# Where does this PropertyChanged event get set?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and as part of that interface I have the member

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

I have the following code for when some property gets changed -

```
public string FavoriteColor
    {
        get { return this.favoriteColor; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.favoriteColor)
            {
                this.favoriteColor = value;
                **if (this.PropertyChanged != null)**
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FavoriteColor"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, I have never set the PropertyChanged variable anywhere in my code, yet if I put a breakpoint at this line it shows that PropertyChanged does have a value. So how is it getting set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you bind to the property the binding system subscribes to the event.